# How to solve an ill-conditioned system of linear equations in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am solving a linear system of few equations (6 equations that has complex coefficients) with `numpy.linalg.solve(A, b)`, where the arrays have `type="complex128"`. The system is solved for a big range of frequencies and from a certain frequency on, the system becomes very much ill-conditioned. When the condition number is in my case over `1E+19` the system becomes unstable so I do not get right solutions. I have tried to use `"clongdouble"` type but it is not supported in `numpy.linalg`.

Are there ideas which is the best workaround to increase the precision or to get the system stable in numpy?

Comment: Use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Do you really need more accuracy? Maybe you can solve the problem by downsizing the magnitude of your numbers?
I have not worked with it myself but the `bigfloat` package provides numbers with arbitrary precision. I don't think it is compatible with `numpy` though...
You could also look into `mpmath` which is referred to by this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442531/increasing-float-point-numbers-accuracy

Comment: I have scaled down the coefficients but it did not help, because the ratio between some coefficients in same equations is very high, what causes the high condition numbers. Besides I cannot scale the coefficients by normalizing input data, because there is not at all linear dependencies of them with the coefficients of the equations. I think the only way is to increase the accuracy. Thanks for suggesting mpmath, I will look it.

Comment: I have just looked in WolframAlpha and is not a practical solution, because I have to solve the system of equations for a large range o frequencies (from 1. to 20000. Hz), besides the coefficients are complex (I mentioned it) and I did not see WolframAlpha includes complex arithmetic for linear systems of equations. So I should twice (once for real part, once for imaginary part) solve the system, lets say with frequency step 10 Hz, i.e. 4000 times by typing the coefficients there.

Comment: With mpmath by defining the required precision with mp.dps I could solve my problem.