# converting a float to decimal type in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that grows with each iteration of a loop:

```
for i in range(100):
    frac[i] = some fraction between 0 and 1 with many decimal places
```

This all works fine. When I check the **type(frac[i])**, I am told that it is **'numpy.float64'**.

For my code to be as precise as I need it to be, I need to use the decimal module and change each **frac[i]** to the decimal type.

I updated my code:

```
for i in range(100):
    frac[i] = some fraction between 0 and 1 with many decimal places

    frac[i] = decimal.Decimal(frac[i])
```

But when I check the type, I am STILL told that **frac[i]** is **'numpy.float64'**.

I have managed to change other variables to decimal in this way before, so I wonder if you could tell me why this doesn't seem to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Converting to a `Decimal` from any kind of float won't add precision; that precision is lost **forever**.

Comment: See a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770870/numpy-array-with-dtype-decimal) on using decimal.Decimal with numpy arrays.

Comment: I understand your point. I don't need to add precision when converting this float to decimal, I am just doing it so that all my variables are decimals, which I seem to need to do in order to get my equations to work.

Comment: You assign to a float array, so the value is cast to float. What else would you expect...

Answer (score 1):

Try doing decimal.Decimal.from_float(frac[i])

Answer (score 1):

Depending where your fractions are coming from, you may find it ideal to use the [fractions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module.  Some examples from the docs:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(16, -10)
Fraction(-8, 5)
>>> Fraction(123)
Fraction(123, 1)
>>> Fraction()
Fraction(0, 1)
>>> Fraction('3/7')
Fraction(3, 7)
>>> Fraction(' -3/7 ')
Fraction(-3, 7)
>>> Fraction('1.414213 \t\n')
Fraction(1414213, 1000000)
>>> Fraction('-.125')
Fraction(-1, 8)
>>> Fraction('7e-6')
Fraction(7, 1000000)
>>> Fraction(2.25)
Fraction(9, 4)
>>> Fraction(1.1)
Fraction(2476979795053773, 2251799813685248)
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Fraction(Decimal('1.1'))
Fraction(11, 10)
```

You can also perform all of the regular arithmetic operations; if the result can't be expressed as a fraction, it will be converted to a float:

```
>>> Fraction(3, 4) + Fraction(1, 16)
Fraction(13, 16)
>>> Fraction(3, 4) * Fraction(1, 16)
Fraction(3, 64)
>>> Fraction(3, 4) ** Fraction(1, 16)
0.982180548555
```

Comment: Thank you. But the number I am using in my example is just a random number really. I just need to convert it to decimal, because I have other decimals in my code (they need to be decimals) and unless I have all variables of the same type, my equations don't seem to work. Hence, I just want to convert these floats to decimals.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I haven't used `numpy` at all, so what follows is mostly just an educated guess.

It sounds like you are using a typed array of type `float64`.  Typed arrays are a particular feature of `numpy` — the elements of arrays (actually Lists) in Python itself can change dynamically from type to type, and there is no need for all elements of a Python list to have the same type.

With a `float64`-type array, your values are being cast to floats *as they are assigned* to array elements, undoing whatever type-casting you've done to them before that point.

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html#intrinsic-numpy-array-creation) for numpy array creation mentions that the default array type is `float64`.  You probably need to change this to `Decimal`.

Adding the keyword argument `dtype=Decimal` to a call to `np.arange` should do this.  You should then have an array of type `Decimal`, and any `float` or `float64` values you assign it should be cast to Decimal.  I don't know enough about what you're doing, or about numpy, to know if this is a sensible thing to be doing with a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing around with Decimals with Numpy.

I found that Numpy offers a function called np.vectorize that allows you to take a function and apply it over a numpy array.
In [23]:

```
import numpy as np

import decimal

D = decimal.Decimal
```

​

We'll create a regular np float array

In [24]:

```
f10 = np.random.ranf(10)

f10
```

Out[24]:

```
array([ 0.45410583,  0.35353919,  0.5976785 ,  0.12030978,  0.00976334,
        0.47035594,  0.76010096,  0.09229687,  0.24842551,  0.30564141])
```

trying to convert the array using np.asarray to Decimal type doesn't work. It seems that trying to use np.asarray and specifying the decimal.Decimal type sets the array to object which is to be expected but if you actually access an individual element of the array it still has a float data type.
In [25]:

```
f10todec = np.asarray(f10, dtype = decimal.Decimal)

print f10todec.dtype, f10todec

print type(f10todec[0])

object [0.454105831376884 0.3535391906233327 0.5976785016396975 0.1203097778312584
 0.009763339031407026 0.47035593879363524 0.7601009625324361
 0.09229687387940333 0.24842550566826282 0.30564141425653435]
<type 'float'>
```

If you give np.array a homogenous python list of Decimal types then it seems to preserve the type, hense the list comprehension below to get a list of the values in the first array as Decimal datatype. So I had to make the decimal array this way.

In [26]:

```
D10 = np.array([D(d) for d in f10])

D10
```

Out[26]:

```
array([Decimal('0.4541058313768839838076019077561795711517333984375'),
       Decimal('0.35353919062333272194109667907468974590301513671875'),
       Decimal('0.597678501639697490332991947070695459842681884765625'),
       Decimal('0.12030977783125840208100498784915544092655181884765625'),
       Decimal('0.00976333903140702563661079693702049553394317626953125'),
       Decimal('0.47035593879363524205672320022131316363811492919921875'),
       Decimal('0.76010096253243608632743644193396903574466705322265625'),
       Decimal('0.09229687387940332943259136300184763967990875244140625'),
       Decimal('0.24842550566826282487653543284977786242961883544921875'),
       Decimal('0.30564141425653434946951847450691275298595428466796875')], dtype=object)
```

basic math operations seem to work ok

In [27]:

```
D10/2
```

Out[27]:

```
array([Decimal('0.2270529156884419919038009539'),
       Decimal('0.1767695953116663609705483395'),
       Decimal('0.2988392508198487451664959735'),
       Decimal('0.06015488891562920104050249392'),
       Decimal('0.004881669515703512818305398469'),
       Decimal('0.2351779693968176210283616001'),
       Decimal('0.3800504812662180431637182210'),
       Decimal('0.04614843693970166471629568150'),
       Decimal('0.1242127528341314124382677164'),
       Decimal('0.1528207071282671747347592373')], dtype=object)
```

In [28]:

```
np.sqrt(D10)
```

Out[28]:

```
array([Decimal('0.6738737503248542354573624759'),
       Decimal('0.5945916166776426405934196108'),
       Decimal('0.7730966961769384578392278689'),
       Decimal('0.3468569991095154505863255680'),
       Decimal('0.09880961001545864636229121433'),
       Decimal('0.6858250059553349663476168402'),
       Decimal('0.8718376927688066448819998853'),
       Decimal('0.3038040057000620415496242404'),
       Decimal('0.4984230187985531079935481296'),
       Decimal('0.5528484550548498633920483390')], dtype=object)
```

Untill you try a trig function for which there is no corresponding function in the decimal module
In [29]:

```
np.sin(D10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-29-31ba62da35b8> in <module>()
----> 1 np.sin(D10)

AttributeError: 'Decimal' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

so lets use np.vectorize so we can use decimal's quantize function to do rounding.

```
In [30]:

    npquantize = np.vectorize(decimal.Decimal.quantize)

    qnt_D10 = npquantize(D10, D('.000001'))

    qnt_D10

Out[30]:

    array([Decimal('0.454106'), Decimal('0.353539'), Decimal('0.597679'),
           Decimal('0.120310'), Decimal('0.009763'), Decimal('0.470356'),
           Decimal('0.760101'), Decimal('0.092297'), Decimal('0.248426'),
           Decimal('0.305641')], dtype=object)
```

You also need to be careful about some regular python math functions because they will automaticaly change the return type to float. I assume this is because the number can't be calculated accuratly based on the function like SIN or COS.

so i guess the short answer is use a list comprehension to get and convert the items in a numpy array to a python list then create that array from the list of Decimals.

To return numpy arrays with their type intact I guess you could use the vectorize function to wrap any function that works with Decimal type to apply over the np array.

On a side note there is a module in the pip that provides numpy style arrays with IEEE Decimals https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decimalpy/0.1