# Summation of large numbers in python yields the maximal parameter

Tags: python, numpy, math, exponent

In my program I use numpy to get number's exponents, then I use the sum function to summarize them.
I've noticed that summarizing those large numbers, with or without numpy, results in the largest parameter being returned, unchanged.

```
exp_joint_probabilities=[  1.57171938e+81,   1.60451506e+56,   1.00000000e+00]
exp_joint_probabilities.sum()
=> 1.571719381352921e+81
```

The same with just python:

```
(1.57171938e+81+1.60451506e+56+1.00000000e+00)==1.57171938e+81
=>True
```

Is this a problem with approximation? Should I use a larger datatype to represent the numbers?
How can I get a more accurate result for these kind of calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.57171938e+81` is a number with 81 digits, of which you only enter the first 9. `1.60451506e+56` is a much much much smaller number, with only 56 digits.

What kind of answer are you expecting? The first utterly dwarfs the second. If you want something of a similar precision to your original numbers (and that's what you get using floats), then the answer is simply correct.

You could use ints:

```
>>> a = int(1.57171938e+81)
>>> b = int(1.60451506e+56)
>>> a
571719379999999945626903548020224083024251666384876684446269499489505292916359168L
>>> b
160451506000000001855754747064077065047170486040598151168L
>>> a+b
1571719379999999945626903708471730083024253522139623748523334546659991333514510336L
```

But how useful that is is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the `decimal` standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal(1.57171938e+81)
b = Decimal(1.60451506e+56)
d = a + b
print(d)
print(d > a and d > b)
```

Output:

```
1.571719379999999945626903708E+81
True
```

You could convert it back to a float afterwards, but this will cause the same problem as before.

```
f = float(d)
print(f)
print(f > a and f > b)
```

Output:

```
1.57171938e+81
False
```

Note that if you store `Decimal`s in your `numpy` arrays, you will lose fast vectorized operations, as [`numpy` does not recognize `Decimal` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7772386/2124834). Though it does work:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.57171938e+81, 1.60451506e+56, 1.00000000e+00])
d = np.vectorize(Decimal)(a)  # convert values to Decimal
print(d.sum())
print(d.sum() > d[0]
```

Output:

```
1.571719379999999945626903708E+81
True
```

Comment: You are still first converting the numbers to the 64bit float approximations and then those approximate values to Decimal. To directly convert the input to Decimal give them as strings, `a = Decimal("1.57171938e+81")` and `b = Decimal("1.60451506e+56")` then `a+b` gives the more correct result `Decimal('1.571719380000000000000000160E+81')`

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a problem with approximation:

```
>>> 1.57171938e+81 + 1.60451506e+65 > 1.57171938e+81
<<< True

>>> 1.57171938e+81 + 1.60451506e+64 > 1.57171938e+81
<<< False
```

You can get arount this by casting to int:

```
>>> int(1.57171938e+81) + int(1.60451506e+64) > int(1.57171938e+81)
<<< True
```

Comment: The `long` cast does not work in Python 3.x. Casting to `int` does work there and I believe that also works in Python 2.x.

Comment: `int` confirmed to work for this purpose in Python 2.7

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that `int` worked in this case, i'll edit my answer, thanks.