# Python: convert matrix of ints to matrix of Decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, python-decimal

I have a Python matrix and due to rounding issues in later parts of the code I would like to convert it to a matrix of `Decimal` elements. I am using Python3. How do I do that?

My matrix is

```
a = [
    [0, 9, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0]
]
```

Something like `b = Decimal(a)` which gives an error.

Comment: Will this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770870/numpy-array-with-dtype-decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the great comment by Denis Rasulev this can be achieved by

```
b = [[Decimal(i) for i in j] for j in a]
```